# Angular2-multiselect-dropdown

Tags: angular

In **angular2-multiselect-dropdown** -> Custom Search/Search from API, I am using custom search that get data from backend api (user data -> firstname and last name) as a list. When i search any user and select the user, it automatically select the other users which are in list.

```
    this.settings = {
      text: "Select Friends",
      selectAllText: 'Select All',
      unSelectAllText: 'UnSelect All',
      classes: "myclass custom-class",
      noDataLabel: "Friends List...",
      enableSearchFilter: true,
      labelKey: "firstName",
      searchBy: ['firstName', 'lastName']
    };
```

Thanks in advance.

Link -> **https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-multiselect-dropdown**

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: better to reproduce the issue on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/)